# Store SQLite 3 Data as a Variable in Python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Is it possible for me to take data stored in a sqlite3 table and use it as a Python variable? I'm looking for something that might be similar to this pseudo-code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
cursor = conn.cursor()
variable = cursor.execute("fetch data from table")
```

Comment: Why can't you just do a SELECT?

Comment: @CL. I wanted to take a specific column from the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a single value from a table, use a SELECT query that returns a result with a single row and a single column:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE ID = ?", [123]):
    variable = row[0]
    break
else:
    variable = 0  # not found
```

Answer (score -2):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).