# FLASK/sqlite3 select query that returns values of data type decimal or numeric

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 select statement that looks like this:

```
con = sql.connect("testDB.db")
            cursor = con.execute("SELECT * from account")
            for row in cursor:
              print row[0]
```

However, whenever i execute it i get a `ValueError: View function did not return a response` whose traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/alex/akiba/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

I had followed the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746348/store-sqlite-3-data-as-a-variable-in-python) with no success

Comment: Is that `return repr(rows)` suppose to be there? Is this an artifact from some mistake when you copied/pasted? This code, as written here, wouldn't even *compile*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga not a copy paste but my one code. It si not supposed to be there. I put it there to see the output of my select squery

Comment: Yes, but that will stop the execution of your function. You probably want `print`. In any event, you need to provide *code that actually represents what you are working with*

Comment: I have edited the question above. I hope i am now clear of what i am looking for

Comment: Your suggestion does not work @CL

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the code shown. You have a problem with how you handle the Flask view function.

Comment: I have actually tested the code on the shell and it works but on flask view on browser it doesn't work. I don't know why. Any suggestions?